# How to avoid error of not defined when trying to show an function?

Tags: javascript, html-table

I'm trying to make a list appear but only when I click on the button. Somehow, when I click on the button, I get an error of function "mostraRceita" not defined and the output already appears even when I don't press in the button.

[image]

```
function mostraTabelaTeste(aTipo, aLista){
    tb = '<table>';
    tb += '<tr><th>Tipo</th><th>Nome</th><th>Tempo</th><th>Custo</th><th>Dificuldade</th><th></th></tr>';
    for(let i in receitas){
      if(receitas[i].tipo==aTipo){
        tb += '<tr><td>' + receitas[i].tipo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].nome + '</td><td> '+ receitas[i].tempo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].custo + '</td><td>' + receitas[i].dificuldade + '</td><td><input type="button" id="mdl" value="Ver receita" onclick="mostraReceita(' + mostraReceita(receitas[i]) + ')"></td></tr>';
      }
    }
    tb += '<table>';
    document.getElementById(aLista).innerHTML = tb;
}


function mostraReceita(aReceita) {
  tb = "<table>";
  tb += "<tr><th>Tipo</th><th>Nome</th><th>Tempo</th><th>Custo</th><th>Dificuldade</th><th>Descrição</th></tr>";
  tb += "<tr><td>" + aReceita.tipo + "</td><td>" + aReceita.nome + "</td><td>" + aReceita.tempo + "</td><td>" + aReceita.custo + "</td><td>" + aReceita.dificuldade + "</td><td>" + aReceita.descricao + "</td></tr>";
  tb += "<table>";
  document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = tb;
  mostrarIngredientesDaReceita(aReceita.listaIngredientes);
}



function mostrarIngredientesDaReceita(aLista) {
      tb = "<table>";
      tb += "<tr><th>Nome</th><th>Quantidade</th></tr>";
      for(let i in aLista){
          tb += "<tr><td>" + aLista[i].nome + "</td><td>" + aLista[i].quantidade + "</td></tr>";
      }
      tb += "<table>";
      document.getElementById("debug1").innerHTML = tb;
}
```

Can someone help me? I'm  new to Javascript so if there are horrible errors, I'm sorry!

Comment: Html code please. i suspect it's a typo `mostraReceita` is your function name not `mostraRceita` you missed one `e` here

Comment: `<div class="row">
        <div class="col-1">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div style="width: 25%; margin: 0 auto 15px;">
            <div id="listacarne" class="centering">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
          <div id="debug" class="centering">
          </div>
          <div id="debug1" class="centering">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>`

Comment: Take a closer look at your button tag: `onclick="mostraReceita(' + mostraReceita(receitas[i]) + ')"`

You are passing the whole function as an argument to the mostraRecieta function. Voce quere pasar solamente a recieita.

`onclick="mostraReceita(receitas[i])"`

Comment: just solved 1 part of the problem, I had    onclick="mostraReceita(' + mostraReceita(receitas[i]) + ')    instead of       onclick="' + mostraReceita(receitas[i]) )+ '

Comment: But now, it never changes, the properties stay the same even when I click in the button.